# Mysql and network latency

Tags: mysql, performance, networking

We have the application that connects to a MySQL DB on the web-server through VPN tunnel.
The problem is, all interactions between the application and the remote DB are extremely slow because of network latency.  I tested the MySQL performance over the network using sysbench and it showed that each query takes almost 1 second. Updating 300+ lines in DB from application takes 20+ minutes.

How can the DB performance over network be improved without moving the server closer to the client? What is the best practice for DB queries over slow networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is network latency (rather than network bandwidth), then the solution is to move as much code into the database as possible.

That is, set up stored procedures to do the work rather than writing code line-by-line.  The stored procedure, in essence, handles multiple lines of code with the overhead of only one round-trip to the database.

This requires intelligent set up, particularly if you have to pass data into the stored procedures.  Consider the following two ways of doing the same thing:

```
insert into X(a) values ('a');
insert into X(a) values ('b');
insert into X(a) values ('c');
```

and

```
insert into X(a)
    select 'a' union all select 'b' union all select 'c';
```

The first requires three round trips because there are three independent statements, the second only one round trip.  In a latency dominated environment, the first will be about three times longer than the second.